# how to filter rows by timeframe in pyspark dataframe

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to filter a data frame by time. my time col is extracted from timestamp col "pickup_datetime" in the format (yyyy-dd-mm HH:mm:ss)  like below -

```
`df = df.withColumn('Pickup_time', date_format('Pickup_datetime', 'HH:mm:ss'))`
```

now i am trying to find all drivers by each day, who drove at night by using the below query

```py
df.withColumn("COUNT", f.lit(1))\
    .groupBy("Pickup_date","Driver_ID")\
    .where((df.Pickup_time >= 01:00:00) & (df.Pickup_time <= 06:00:00)) \
    .agg(f.sum("COUNT").alias("Total_Rides"))\
    .orderBy("Pickup_date", ascending=False)
```

Am I extracting time correctly in the right format?, if yes then why won't my Query work?

[image: First half of table]
[image: Second Half of table]

Answer (score 0):

try

```
df.filter(df["Pickup_time"] >= lit('01:00:00')) \
       .filter(df["Pickup_time"] <= lit('06:00:00'))
```